# Using selenium ( and requests.get) to check if a website has a specific word

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I'm trying to build a Python program that automatically answers specific questions.

But before I can build that algorithm I need to read the site and make an if-statement that finds the words I'm looking for and fills in a form. Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import urllib 
import requests 

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\chromedriver.exe" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH) driver.get("site") 
words = ['JulkiTerhikki', 'Mikä', 'Lähetä'] 
site = requests.get("site").read() 
HTML = site.decode("utf-8") 

for word in words: 
    if word in site: 
        print(word) 
    else: 
        print(word, "not found") 
    time.sleep(2) 

driver.quit()
```

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: from selenium import webdriver 
import urllib
import requests
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://julkiterhikki.valvira.fi/")
words = ['JulkiTerhikki', 'Mikä', 'Lähetä']
site = requests.get("https://julkiterhikki.valvira.fi/").read()
HTML = site.decode("utf-8")

for word in words:
    if word in site:
       print(word)
    else:
       print(word, "not found")
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()

Comment: Added code from comment to question text. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Here is version using requests:

```
import requests

words = ['JulkiTerhikki', 'Mikä', 'Lähetä'] 
site = requests.get("http://julkiterhikki.valvira.fi").content 
HTML = site.decode("utf-8") 

for word in words: 
    if word in HTML: 
        print(word) 
    else: 
        print(word, "not found")
```

Here is version using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

words = ['JulkiTerhikki', 'Mikä', 'Lähetä'] 

PATH = "<<PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER>>" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH) 
driver.get("http://julkiterhikki.valvira.fi")
HTML = driver.page_source


for word in words: 
    if word in HTML: 
        print(word) 
    else: 
        print(word, "not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

U can do this just with selenium (without using requests), like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://julkiterhikki.valvira.fi/')

words = ['JulkiTerhikki', 'Mikä', 'Lähetä']

html = driver.page_source

words_present = [x for x in words if x in html]

print(words_present)
```

Output:

```
['JulkiTerhikki']
```